# Python thread safety for method/attribute lookup

Tags: python, multithreading, cpython

I have been working with python and I understand and use the threading, queues, events, locks in a multi threaded environment. What I am curious about is while accesing and calling a shared object's method can we ignore any locks and semaphores?
Here is a sample code:

```
import threading

class Methods(object):

    def method1(self):
        # assume there is no need for a lock
        # only local variables are used
        pass

    def method2(self):
        # assume there is no need for a lock
        # only local variables are used
        pass

methods = Methods()

def thread1():
    # instance method is found from instance dictionary
    # and called
    methods.method1()

def thread2():
    # instance method is found from instance dictionary
    # and called
    methods.method2()

thr1 = threading.Thread(None, thread1)
thr2 = threading.Thread(None, thread2)

thr1.start() # assume thr1 and thr2 is started at the same time
thr2.start()

thr1.join()
thr2.join()
```

Thread 1 and Thread 2 calls the same `methods` `method1` and `method2` at the same time (just assume). `methods.method1` and `methods.method2` cause a dictionary lookup using `self.__dict__` or `__getattribute__` method, right?
So, do we need any locks in this simple scenario? I wonder if internal dictionary lookup of an instance is atomic and what happens if `self.__dict__` is updated somehow during execution. I have not found such resource on the internet. I appreciate if you could help me to clarify these thoughts.

Comment: I think you might need to give more information about what the threads and methods are doing. Generally if you're only ever getting data and not modifying it, not locks are needed.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Methods do not change global variables.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you use only local variables then its ok, but if you only use local variables in your methods (I mean you don't access attributes of `self`), maybe it's better to make them staticmethods or plain functions?